# Hatcher's Question 2.3.2

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In Section 2.3, on p. 165, Hatcher asks the following as exercise 2:

> **2.** Define a candidate for a reduced homology theory on CW complexes by $\tilde{h}_n (X) = \prod_i \tilde{H}_i (X) / \bigoplus_i \tilde{H}_i (X)$. Thus $\tilde{h}_n (X)$ is independent of $n$ and is zero if $X$ is finite-dimensional, but is not identically zero, for example for $X = \bigvee_i S^{i}$. Show that the axioms for a homology theory are satisfied except that the wedge axiom fails.

Well, assuming that the first two axioms have been proven to hold true, the question is, how does one prove that the final one does not hold true? I try the following: We start with $X = \bigvee_{\alpha} X_{\alpha}$. Taking $\tilde{h}_n$ of the spaces on both sides, we have
$$\tilde{h}_n (X) = \prod_{i} \tilde{H}_i (X) / \bigoplus_{j} \tilde{H}_j (X) \cong \prod_{i} \bigoplus_{\alpha} \tilde{H}_i (X_{\alpha}) / \bigoplus_{j} \bigoplus_{\beta} \tilde{H}_j (X_{\beta}) = \bigoplus_{\alpha} \left( \prod_{i} \tilde{H}_i (X_{\alpha}) / \bigoplus_{j, \beta} \tilde{H}_j (X_{\beta}) \right),$$
and
$$\bigoplus_{\alpha} \tilde{h}_n (X_{\alpha}) = \bigoplus_{\alpha} \left( \prod_{i} \tilde{H}_i (X_{\alpha}) / \bigoplus_{j} \tilde{H}_j (X_{\alpha}) \right).$$
I say that these two are not necessarily isomorphic, and so the wedge axiom fails.

Am I correct (this does seem a bit too easy), or am I *completely* missing the point of what I am supposed to be doing? If the latter, could you please offer me a hint?

As always, I look forward to your answers.

Comment: The point of the exercise is to prove the other axioms hold. Hatcher himself proves the wedge doesn’t when stating the exercise.

Comment: @ConnorMalin : Embarrassed that I didn't forgot to say this immediately, but you are entirely right, and I thank you for helping me clear up this silly little mistake! :)